# Cursor Glitch Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: bug-reporting, cursor, 21.04

I installed Ubuntu 21.01 as dual boot with Windows 10 two weeks ago.
Except that there is some sort of square/rectangle around my mouse that "draws" over anything behind it and follows the cursor around.I tried `sudo service gdm`, but it isn't working at all. Does anyone know of a permanent solution to this?

## My Video Card Details

`sudo lshw -C video`

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:137 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PeCT.png)

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your video driver. What video card do you have? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1347738/edit) and show me `sudo lshw -C video`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I added what you asked into the question

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema no helping tried all

Comment: You have to give me more details about what you tried, and any specific results. You might also check that **Zoom** is disabled in the Settings/Accessibility panel. You can also log into a different user account (create one if you need to) and see if the problem occurs there also.

Answer (score 0):

AMD does a poor job of supporting their video cards in Linux.

Try one of these two solutions...

1. Start `Software & Updates` and check the **Additional Drivers** tab and see if there's a video driver available there to select from...

[image]

2. Install the free open source Oibaf driver that supports Ubuntu 21.04... [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers..](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers..). (you probably need to uninstall the current Radeon driver first)...

All Ubuntu architectures are supported.

Supported Ubuntu versions:

- 20.04 (focal) <- supported
- 20.10 (groovy) <- obsolete
- 21.04 (hirsute) <- supported
- 21.10 (impish) <- supported

For forum support see: http://goo.gl/qoUpWK

=== Introduction ===
This PPA provides updated free graphics drivers packages for radeon, intel and nvidia hardware. Updates packages provide:

- all driver packages are automagically built every day, when there are upstream changes
- Vulkan 1.2+ and OpenGL 4.6+ : http://mesamatrix.net
- gallium-nine support. Read the specific section below
- VDPAU and VAAPI Gallium3D accelerated video drivers (see below)
- packages built against latest stable LLVM
- mesa packages built with gcc LTO for smaller binary size (~10-15%) and improved performance

As an added bonus I may include some updated open source games (backported from Debian or newer Ubuntu).

=== Basic usage ===
See "Adding this PPA to your system" later on, or just do:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
and update your Ubuntu with the package here.

=== Using gallium-nine ===
Gallium-nine lets you run DirectX 9 games in a faster way, avoiding the inefficient translation of D3D9 calls to OpenGL. For more info see https://wiki.ixit.cz/d3d9
You need:

- enable this PPA (see previous paragraph)
- then follow the instructions to install wine from this PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~commendsarnex/+archive/ubuntu/winedri3](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecommendsarnex/+archive/ubuntu/winedri3)

=== Using alternative drivers - Here be dragons ===

- zink - OpenGL emulated on a Vulkan driver:
  Set MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
- Old Intel i965 OpenGL driver (iris is the default):
  Set MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
- llvmpipe OpenGL software render:
  Set MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=llvmpipe
- Other options here: https://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html

=== Using accelerated video ===
Supported VDPAU drivers: r300, r600, radeonsi, nouveau
Supported VAAPI drivers: r600, radeonsi

- First you need to install mesa-vdpau-drivers package:
  sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers
- Then to test the VDPAU driver with mpv use:
  $ mpv --hwdec=vdpau yourvideofile

=== Upgrading to a newer Ubuntu ===
It is *strongly* suggested to remove all packages from this PPA before updating to a newer Ubuntu release. See the section "Revert to original drivers" later on.
Then, after the upgrade, you can add again this PPA.

=== Debugging and reporting problems ===
If you have some problem with the drivers try running the application from the command line and see if there are graphics related warnings. Also type dmesg to see if there are other related information here.

If you get crashes install the relevant -dbg pacakges (libgl1-mesa-dri-dbg or libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental-dbg for 3D drivers and xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg , xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-dbg or xserver-xorg-video-radeon-dbg for X drivers) and reproduce the crash with gdb. Example:
$ gdb glxgears
[...make your application crash and then get a backtrace with:]
(gdb) bt

If X.org crashes look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log (or /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old when a new X session is started after the crash).

With the gathered information try searching at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/query.cgi (also try with google) if someone already reported a similar bug. If not you may want to report a new bug:
for 3D drivers bugs: https://www.mesa3d.org/bugs.html
for X / 2D driver bugs: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=xorg

=== Revert to original drivers ===
To revert to standard Ubuntu drivers type the following in a prompt shell:
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

=== Donations ===
Some people asked me if I can accept donations to support this work. I don't, but if you have some spare money I would be happy if you could do a donation to a charity of your choice (for the poors, animals, whatever else you may think it might need it). Then feel free to send me a note about it!
Adding this PPA to your system

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers to your system's Software Sources. (Read about installing)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```